# run code in parallel in python (pika library)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

i have a pika receiver that receives commands and executes another python script. the problem is i'm unable to run the script in parallel as multiprocess or threading. if i receive the command via the mqtt protocol, it waits until it finishes the "make.py" function to execute it again. i wanted it to run in parallel. someone can help?

```
def call_mkdt(ch, method, properties, body):
    os.system(f"make.py {body}")


def consume():
    channel.basic_consume(queue='UploadCompleted', on_message_callback=call_mkdt, auto_ack=True)
    print(' [*] ETL')
    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        channel.stop_consuming()

if __name__== "__main__":
    p1 = threading.Thread(name="Hello1", target=consume)
    p1.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't want to wait for the `make.py` to finish the execution,
You can use `subprocess.Popen` function from python's  `subprocess` module.

You can refer more about `Popen` function at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

**Replace:**

```
def call_mkdt(ch, method, properties, body):
    os.system(f"make.py {body}")
```

**With:**

```
import subprocess

def call_mkdt(ch, method, properties, body):
    subprocess.Popen(["make.py", f"{body}"])
```